# How to join three RDDs using the Python Core API (Apache Spark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to join thee RDDs together using the Python Core API, which is through Apache Spark; however, I am having no luck trying to accomplish this.

At the moment, I have these three RDDs with the common attributes:

- users_rdd: user_id
- reviews_rdd: review_id, company_id and user_id
- companies_rdd: company_id

Now, when joining two of the RDDs together, it works perfectly fine with no issues:

```
user_rev_rdd = (users_rdd
  .keyBy(lambda user: user['user_id'])
  .join(
      reviews_rdd.keyBy(lambda rev: rev['user_id'])
  )
)
```

Though, in order to join all three together, I have tried this, but it does not work for me at all for some reason:

```
user_rev_com_rdd = (users_rdd
  .keyBy(lambda user: user['user_id'])
  .join(
      reviews_rdd.keyBy(lambda rev: rev['user_id'])
  )
 .join(
      companies_rdd.keyBy(lambda com: com['company_id'])
  )
)
```

Any assistance on how to join all three of my RDDs together would be very helpful, as I am unsure how to do such a thing correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first join, the key is `user_id`, but you're joining to `companies_rdd` with the key being `company_id`, so the joining key is incorrect. You need to change the key to `company_id`, e.g.

```
user_rev_com_rdd = (users_rdd
    .keyBy(lambda user: user['user_id'])
    .join(
        reviews_rdd.keyBy(lambda rev: rev['user_id'])
    )
    .map(lambda r: (r[1][1]['company_id'], r[1]))
    .join(
        companies_rdd.keyBy(lambda com: com['company_id'])
    )
)
```

To combine the elements from the three RDDs and remove the joining keys after joining, you can add a `map` at the end:

```
user_rev_com_rdd = (users_rdd
    .keyBy(lambda user: user['user_id'])
    .join(
        reviews_rdd.keyBy(lambda rev: rev['user_id'])
    )
    .map(lambda r: (r[1][1]['company_id'], r[1]))
    .join(
        companies_rdd.keyBy(lambda com: com['company_id'])
    )
    .map(lambda r: (*r[1][0], r[1][1]))
)
```